# Postorder traversal using recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, postorder

I am a new to python programming and recently I have experienced some problems in programming recursions.Consider I have a Graph as : a)list of vertices b) and an adjacency list (as a 2 dimensional list) and I am trying to get an lists which will give me the Postorder traversal order of these vertices(Post_Order_List_of_Node), an inverse of this which will tell the order of any node(Order_of_Node) and a list of father of all nodes. I have written the following piece of code:

My "order" variable is global but according to output, its not getting incremented.

I dont know why but the variable "order" isnt getting updated.

```
def Post_Order(node,order,father):
    Order_of_Node = [No_of_Nodes]*No_of_Nodes   #Initialization
    Post_Order_List_of_Node = [No_of_Nodes]*No_of_Nodes     #Initialization
    def recursive(node,order,father):
        if len(Spanning_Tree[node]) == 0:
            Order_of_Node[node] = order
            Post_Order_List_of_Node[order] = node
            order = order + 1
            Father_List[node] = father
            del(Spanning_Tree[father][0])
            return
        else:
            while(len(Spanning_Tree[node])!=0): 
            recurse(Spanning_Tree[node][0],order,node)
    recurse(node,order,father)
    return Post_Order_List_of_Node,Order_of_Node
Father_List = [0]*No_of_Nodes
root = 0
father = 0
order = 1
Order = []
Order = Post_Order(root,order,father)
```

Comment: Ok so I wasn't able to post the test input and the output as Stackoverflow was thinking that it was also part of code and not letting me post the question. So here it goes:
For eg my Tree is : "[[1, 2], [3], [], [4], [5, 6], [], []]"
but my Order_of_Node is : "[7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]"
and Post_Order_List_of_Node = "[7, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]"

Comment: You code is inconsistent and unconventional (variable names, spacing), etc. It will be more difficult to read it because of that.

Comment: This code won't work, because `Post_Order()` is defined after it's used. Perhaps there're other mistakes.

Comment: Sorry for the poor editing. Actully all the initializations are done below the function. Fixed?

Comment: @PaulDraper: Why do you say its unconventional? All sites say visit a node. If it has child, go down. Else number it. I think i am doing the same. Creating Adjacency List(i.e Spanning_Tree) might be a little unconventional.

Comment: You define `recursive`, but call `recurse`. Typo?

Comment: Where is `Spanning_Tree` defined? The standard Python convention is that class names are capitalized `LikeThis`; all other variable  and function names are spelled `like_this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is not getting updated because, unlike what you claim, it is *not* a global variable. By defining your `recursive` function like this,

```
def recursive(node,order,father):
```

any reference to `order` within the scope of that function will only modify the parameter, not the global variable. Within that function, you only modify `order` in the `if` branch, but use it in the `else` branch. So the update to the parameter never gets passed on.

In order to use `order` as a global variable, declare it as such:

```
def recursive(node, father):
    global order
    if ...
```

---

Another issue in your code - when you set values for `Post_Order_List_of_Node`, you use

```
Post_Order_List_of_Node[order] = node
```

However, `order` starts at 1 instead of at 0, so for the last node you'll get an error. You need to use

```
Post_Order_List_of_Node[order-1] = node
```

instead.

---

One inefficiency that you may or may not have noticed is in how you process nodes:

```
def recursive(node,father):
    if len(Spanning_Tree[node]) == 0:
        # Process node
    else:
        while(len(Spanning_Tree[node])!=0): 
            # Process child
```

In one call to `recursive`, you only process the children **or** the node itself. Your code works because of the `while` loop - you call `recursive` twice for each child that has children itself. Instead of doing it that way, you could switch it to do this:

```
def recursive(node,father):
    for child in Spanning_Tree[node]:
        # process child
    # process node
```

This has the added advantage that it does not require modifying `Spanning_Tree`. However, it does require that you either make sure that you do have a tree (no cycles) or that you mark nodes as visited before you start processing any children.